# Laravel Migration Error When Connecting With My Database on MyPHPAdmin

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I am new to Laravel and myphpadmin so I am assuming I am making a stupid mistake while entering parameters into my env file. Also, keep in mind that I am using a brand new copy of myphpadmin that was included with MAMP (I haven't altered username or password at all).

Here is my error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = mysql an
d table_name = migrations)
```

at

```
/Users/christian/Desktop/lsapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }

Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /Users/christian/Desktop/lsapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=8080;dbname=mysql", "root", "", [])
      /Users/christian/Desktop/lsapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68
```

Here is my env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8080
DB_DATABASE=lsapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Try `DB_PORT=3306`

Answer (score 0):

In your env file, try change to:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

Also are you sure mysql is running on 8080? Mine is normally 3306

Comment: @Chistian The tip about changing port to 3306 should be enough. As a side suggestion, why not, instead of MAMP, using homestead (as in laravel docs) for your dev. You can also use mySql Workbench instead of myphpadmin...

Comment: I have tried changing the host to 127.0.0.1 and that doesn't work. Furthermore my localhost link for myphpadmin is http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=9571f7ace2fd54d5be604a8bbbf64ba0

Comment: @ChristianLessard did you try 3306 in your env file?

Comment: @d3t0x yes, but as you can see from my previous comment the port is 8080

Answer (score 0):

8080 is your Apache port, despite it showing up in the url of your PHPMyAdmin, it is not the value you need to put in your .env

Your MAMP instalation should mention a seperate MySQL Port that you need to use for the DB_PORT value.

Comment: I then changed my env to this (which didn't work): DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lsapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: The port was wrong in your original post. if your MAMP installation says the MySQL port is 3306, then there is a second problem. I suggest  DB_PASSWORD=root